# FLUTTER / FIRESTORE - Retrieving DATA which is nested in several subcollections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a database using Firestore. The main collection is "familyAccounts". Inside each account : you have info, and a subcollections of USERS (each account offers two Users (two differents user profiles), which have data too... So data is nested in various subcollections.
Here is how I "set" data in the database :

```
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
//
 if (newUser != null) {
                              _fireStore
                                  .collection('familyAccounts')
                                  .doc(email)
                                  .set({
                                'name': '$name $firstName',
                                'country': country,
                                'region': region,
                              });
                              _fireStore
                                  .collection('familyAccounts')
                                  .doc(email)
                                  .collection('users')
                                  .doc('user1')
                                  .set({
                                'userId': 'Utilisateur n°1',
                                'teacherCode': '',
                                'avatar': 'icons/avatar.jpg',
                                'vocLists': [],
                              });
                              _fireStore
                                  .collection('familyAccounts')
                                  .doc(email)
                                  .collection('users')
                                  .doc('user2')
                                  .set({
                                'userId': 'Utilisateur n°2',
                                'teacherCode': '',
                                'avatar': 'icons/avatar.jpg',
                                'vocLists': [],
                              });
```

This works fine. But now, no matter what I try, I just do not understand how to retrieve this data. It was so easy to add it to the database. I have been reading online and am totally lost.

To make it as clear as possible : when the user logs in the app : he/she types in email and password : if account info is correct (using firebase_auth (this works)) then, I want to retrieve the data for both users linked to the account. Once I get the data, I use Provider to make it accessible wherever it will be needed in the app.

Can someone Help ? Thanks in advance :)

So far : I have managed to do this : I have created a function :

```
final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('familyAccounts');

  getUserById(String id) async {
     
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await _fireStore.doc(id).get();
    print(doc.data());
    print(doc.id);
    print(doc.exists);
  }
```

It gives me the "first level" of data... But how can I dig deeper...?

Comment: You will need to [make a query](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) to find documents you added.  Please edit the question to show what you tried that doesn't work in the way you expect.

Comment: I have read about the querying : but just can't get the syntax when you have to query inside nested subcollections. I am stuck right now, don't really have code to show unfortunately. I keep erasing what I try :( I have tried several things with "snapshot", but it was just all very confusing. It's hard to understand why it is so easy to write data and apparently so hard to retrieve it :(

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to write the code for you - you should review the documentation and make an attempt and explain what doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: OK I understand. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Can you give me a clue as the way I can reach the data that's nested in "FamilyAccounts" > "email (Id of the account)"> "users" > "user1" {data} ?

Comment: Build a collection reference to query just like you did when you added the document.  If you are having problems getting started, perhaps you should begin with a more simple structure to learn how things work.  There are a lot of great tutorials and other documentation out there to follow.